# When I union two datasets in Snowflake SQL, Should the length, Scale and precision be exactly same between two tables?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sqldatatypes

```
Table 1
ID value  DataType
001    A    VARCHAR(10)
002    A    VARCHAR(10)
003    B    VARCHAR(10)
004    C    VARCHAR(10)

Table 1
ID value  DataType
001    A    VARCHAR(100)
002    A    VARCHAR(100)
003    B    VARCHAR(100)
004    C    VARCHAR(100)
```

Will the Union in Snowflake be safe, if the datatype is same but the length, scale and precision differs between two tables?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to worry about string lengths, but you do have to watch out for numeric scale and precision when doing unions. Here's an example:

```
create or replace table TABLE_A(MY_NUM number(38,0));
create or replace table TABLE_B(MY_NUM number(38,37));

insert into TABLE_A (MY_NUM) values (12345);
insert into TABLE_B (MY_NUM) values (1.23456789);

select * from TABLE_A
union all 
select * from TABLE_B
```

Running this will give you the error:

> Number out of representable range: type FIXEDSB16{nullable}, value 12345

In this case, the optimizer can't win. If it casts that column to NUMBER(38,0) then the value in TABLE_B would be truncated silently. If it casts to NUMBER(38,37), then it cannot represent a number with more than one place before the decimal point as stored in TABLE_A.

If you make sure the optimizer can always find a way to reconcile the precisions and scales for the column, it will be safe. If there is a possibility that one table's column can hold a value that the other table cannot, it may not be safe. If there is a standoff situation like the example here where two or more tables have values other tables in the union cannot represent then it's unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

No - the scale and precision don't have to be the same - just the datatype